# In Bootstrap what are these fake horizontal rules beneath headers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, divider

There's an example of what I mean on some of Bootstrap's own pages: 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/
Under the header text "Glyphicons" see how there's a 1px high grey horizontal line? It's some divider that gets automatically inserted under headers but I can't figure out what style property needs to be changed to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override the `.page-header` class, if you're looking to remove it then do this in a stylesheet loaded after the bootstrap styles:

```
.page-header { border-bottom:none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a `border-bottom` declaration on the `.page-header` class.

Here's the full code from the CSS:

```
.page-header {
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    margin: 40px 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

You can modify the colour using the following CSS in your own stylesheet included after Bootstrap's own:

```
.page-header {
    border-color: #aaa;
}
```